# how to solve system.argumentexception parameter is not valid. at system.drawing.bitmap..ctor(int32 width, int32 height, pixelformat format)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, bitmap, .net-4.8

i have a project that captures images by basler camera and for this i have a onimagegrabbed Function that grabs image.
while running my project in any cpu it i did not getting any error. but when i turned to x86 , project runs but after 2 or 3 seconds I am getting exception message " system.argumentexception parameter is not valid. at system.drawing.bitmap..ctor(int32 width, int32 height, pixelformat format) ."

also gettig this message in this in console tab
"Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll"

[the exception message screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqZUR.png)

heres what i have tried

```
private void OnImageGrabbed(object sender, ImageGrabbedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool invokeRequired = base.InvokeRequired;
            if (invokeRequired)
            {
                base.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<ImageGrabbedEventArgs>(this.OnImageGrabbed), new object[]
                {
                    sender,
                    e.Clone()
                });
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    this.grabResult = e.GrabResult;
                    bool isValid = this.grabResult.IsValid;
                    if (isValid)
                    {
                        bool flag = !this.stopWatch.IsRunning || this.stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 33L;
                        if (flag)
                        {
                            this.stopWatch.Restart();
                            Bitmap bitmap =  new Bitmap(this.grabResult.Width, this.grabResult.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
                            this.converter.OutputPixelFormat = PixelType.BGRA8packed;
                            IntPtr scan = bitmapData.Scan0;
                            this.converter.Convert(scan, (long)(bitmapData.Stride * bitmap.Height), this.grabResult);
                            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
                            object obj = this.lockObject;
                            lock (obj)
                            {
                                Bitmap bitmap2 = this.DisplayWindow.Image as Bitmap;
                                bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                                this.gb = this.CreateNonIndexedImage(bitmap);
                                this.DisplayWindow.Image = bitmap;
                                bool flag3 = bitmap2 != null;
                                if (flag3)
                                {
                                    bitmap2.Dispose();



                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    e.DisposeGrabResultIfClone();
                }
            }
        }
```

the line:150  is " Bitmap bitmap =  new Bitmap(this.grabResult.Width, this.grabResult.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);"

Comment: just run the code in any cpu configuration unless you are targeting 32 bit systems to run the software

Comment: but i am now going to use x86 because openCV is prefers x86 or x64.

Comment: 1) What is `DisplayWindow`?  Is it a `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`?  Some other [tag:winforms] control?  Something else?  2) Might you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any? 3) What is `this.gb`?  Do old values need to be disposed after setting a new value, the way you are doing with `DisplayWindow.Image`?

Comment: Why do you store GrabResult in a field (`this.grabResult = e.GrabResult`)? Do you access this field from somewhere else? Dangerous because it is disposed at the end of the event handler.

Comment: If you run the code in the debugger, what are the values of width and height when the exception occurs?

Comment: @dbc DisplayWindow is where i am showing the preview from camera.

Comment: @KlausGütter  i have check the width and height i'm getting are 1280 and 1024